# Jquery showing and hiding issues with child divs

Tags: jquery, css

My code below opens and shows the content individuall.  When the content is displayed, I want to hide the href which contains class "**item-show**" the problem I am having is hiding ".**item-show**" when the content is shown .
The close button when clicked should hide the content and show the href again, but currently it's not closing.

Here is my Code below  and [fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/n7305445/39/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item-content").hide();
    $(".item-show").on("click hover", function() {
       $(this).parent('p').next(".item-content").slideDown( "slow" );
       $(this).parent('p').next('.item-show').hide();  
    });
    $("span.close-icon").on("click hover", function() {
       $(this).parent('p').next(".item-content").slideUp( "slow" );
      $(this).parent('p').next('.item-show').show(); 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n7305445/29/

use `.slideToggle()` to toggle `.item-content`

use `.closest()` and `.find()` to navigate through the DOM tree

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //PREVIEW CARD 
    $(".item-content").hide();
    $(".item-show").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest('.item-b').find(".item-content").slideToggle( "slow" );
    });
    $("span.close-icon").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest('.item-content').slideUp( "slow" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go.

https://jsfiddle.net/zsdgjsz7/

```
//PREVIEW CARD 
    $(".item-content").hide();
    $(".item-show").on("click hover", function() {
       $(this).hide().parent('p').next(".item-content").slideDown( "slow" );
    });
    $("span.close-icon").on("click hover", function() {
       $(this).parent('.item-content').slideUp('slow').parent().find('.item-show').show();

    });
```